# NoSuchMethodError : The getter 'title' was called on null. Receiver : null. Tried calling: title. //Anyone please

Tags: flutter, dart, getter, nosuchmethoderror

These are some of my todo_detail.dart code. Please help me. In the debug console it says

```
The relevant error-causing widget was
TodoDetail
lib/Screens/todo_list.dart:100
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#1      TodoDetailState.build
package:todo_list/Screens/todo_detail.dart:35



class TodoDetail extends StatefulWidget {
  TodoDetail(this.todo, this.appBarTitle);

  final String appBarTitle;
  final Todo todo;

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return TodoDetailState(this.todo, this.appBarTitle);
  }
}

class TodoDetailState extends State<TodoDetail> {
  DatabaseHelper helper = DatabaseHelper();

  String appBarTitle;
  Todo todo;

  TextEditingController titleController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController descriptionController = TextEditingController();

  TodoDetailState(this.todo, this.appBarTitle);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    TextStyle textStyle = Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6;
    final Todo todo = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;

    titleController.text = todo.title;
    descriptionController.text = todo.description,......
```

[This is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNi08.jpg) of the error after built it on my physical device

Comment: `ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments` returns null. Be sure that it is not null

Comment: Please don't post images whenever possible - see [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Todo` is passed as a `Widget` argument in the code above, hence, we could access it by:

```
final Todo todo = widget.todo;
```

Full code example:

```
class TodoDetailState extends State<TodoDetail> {
  DatabaseHelper helper = DatabaseHelper();

  String appBarTitle;
  Todo todo;

  TextEditingController titleController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController descriptionController = TextEditingController();

  TodoDetailState(this.todo, this.appBarTitle);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       TextStyle textStyle = Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6;
       final Todo todo = widget.todo;
       titleController.text = todo.title;
       descriptionController.text = todo.description;
       return Container();
    }
}
```